# Is it possible to run a simple attack on a previous version of the client in testnet mode?

Tags: testnet, attack

I need to simulate an attack locally or in testnet (if possible) for academic purpose, on an old and bugged version of the bitcoin core client. I am in posses of test BTC in the last version. I want to know an easy way to exploit one this listed vulnerabilities(https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures), if this has been done before or if im speaking nonsense.

Comment: Hi Similarion, it is not clear what you need, could you please add a few more details so people have a better idea what to look out for in an answer?

Comment: Added infos hope it helps